# Why do I get multiple rows with Sum() and GroupBy

Tags: sql, sum

When I sum a column, I get a single result of all rows summed up. When I group by on this summed column, I get returned multiple rows.
Can someone explain what is going on? Is it secretly grouping all the rows with data that is the same and summing these all up first as separate rows?

Table Column Data is

```
9.75
2.25
8.25
8.25
7
8
5
10.5
5
10.5
10.5
10.25
10.5
10.5
5
5
0.5
5
5
0.5
5
5
0.5
5
5
0.5
5
5
0.5
5
5
0.5
5
5
0.5
5
5
0.5
5
5
0.5
5
5
0.5
1.5
5
1.75
0.5
5
5
0.5
1.5
5
1.75
0.5
5
5
0.5
5
5
0.5
5
5
0.5
5
5
0.5
5
5
0.5
5
5
0.5
5
5
0.5
5
5
0.5
1.75
5
5
0.5
5
10
10
10
10
5
0.5
5
5
0.5
1.75
5
1.5
0.5
5
5
0.5
5
5
0.5
NULL
```

The Result I get from "Group By column"

```
Select Sum(column) as [column]
From Table
Group By column  

(Result)
NULL
13.5
4.5
7
2.25
265
7
8
16.5
9.75
40
10.25
52.5
```

The result from just the Sum

```
Select Sum(column) as [column]
From Table

(result)
436.25
```

Answer (score 1):

[`count`, `avg`, and `sum`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) are all [aggregate functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function). They take a group of rows and aggregate them together into one value. `count` gives the number of rows, `avg` gives their mean, and `sum` sums them up.

By default all rows are aggregated together. [`group by`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) allows you to split things up into more groups. When you `group by column` you say to aggregate together all the rows with the same value for `column`. So you're getting the sums of all rows with the same value for `column`.

You can see this by also selecting the column and the count.

```
select column, count(column), sum(column)
from table
group by column
```

You'll find that `sum(column)` is `column` times `count(column)`. For example.

```
column, count(column), sum(column)
1.5     3              4.5
8       1              8
10      4              40
```

Comment: I see. My error was in how I originally applied the Group By using it with the column that led to my unexpected result. 
Not fully understating the order in which these are processed. With your explanation, I can see now how expecting all the rows to be summed first and then Grouping by that column would make no sense.

Comment: @changedsoul If you want to group by the sums, use a subquery to first make the sums. Then group by the summed column from the subquery.